# Negative factors vs positive factors

Tags: factoring

I'm learning about factoring and the lecturer show this example:

$$-3x^2+12x-18$$

For start he factor this polynomial like:

$$3(-x^2+4x-6)$$

So far so good but now he said:

> In some circumstances it's more valuable to us to take out negative
>   factor than positive factor

And now:

$$-3(x^2-4x+6)$$

I really don't know why should to prefer negative factor than positive factor, is there a special reason?

Comment: For me, it is way easier to decompose $\;x^2-4x+6\;$ in factors, if possible and more or less easy, than $\;-x^2+4x-6\;$ . That's all. It *looks* easier and more manageable. Perhaps your lecturer is similar to me in this.

Comment: It is sometimes more convenient to work with a polynomial like $x^2-4x+6$, whose leading coefficient is positive, than with one like $-x^2+4x-6$, whose leading coefficient is negative. Sometimes the convenience is mostly psychological; occasionally, though, it’s more than that.

Comment: Monic polynomials FTW. they are the reason why I always look at $\det(xI-A)$ instead of $\det(A-xI)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it is a matter of getting the remaining polynomial to have a leading factor of $+1$. it is just a bit easier to factor a polynomial with leading coefficient $+1$.  For example, a quadratic like 
$$
x^2 + bx + c$$
factors into $$(x+r)(x+s)$$
with 
$$rs = c \\ r+s = b$$
So if you have a hunch that the polynomial given will factor "nicely" you need only look for pairs of factors of the constant term.

For example, to factor $x^2+5x+6$ you only have to try
$$ (x+1)(x+6) \\ (x+2)(x+3) \\ (x-1)(x-6) \\ (x-2)(x-3)
$$
one of these must work if the polynomial has rational factors.  In the case I showed, the second wone works because $2+3=5$.